# Higher order covariant derivative chain rule

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $\nabla_v$ be the covariant derivative in the $v$ direction for all $v\in T_xM$, and denote with $\nabla^k h$ the $(k,0)$-tensor field defined in local coordinates inductively by
$$
\nabla^0h=dh,\quad(\nabla^kh)_{i_1,\dots,i_k}=(\nabla_{\partial_{i_1}}h)_{i_2,\dots,i_k}.
$$
for any smooth function $h$.

> My question is: is there a nice way to express the difference $\nabla\nabla_udh-\nabla_u\nabla dh$?

To avoid confusion, I am considering the expression given by
$$
\nabla(\nabla_udh)(X,Y)-\nabla_u(\nabla dh)(X,Y)=\nabla_X(\underbrace{\nabla_udh}_{(1,0) -tensor\,field})(Y)-\nabla_u(\underbrace{\nabla dh}_{(2,0)-tensor\,field})(X,Y).
$$
This looks somehow similar to the Riemannian curvature tensor applied to forms. I have tried to develop the difference, but I cannot see anything familiar. More generally (but maybe I am asking too much), is there a nice way to write
$$
\nabla^k\nabla_udh-\nabla_u\nabla^kdh=?
$$

Comment: Your inductive definition of $\nabla^kh$ seems to be wrong. (And is it called $(0,k)$ instead of $(k,0)$ tensor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\nabla_u dh = c^1_1 ( u\otimes \nabla dh)$, where $c^1_1$ is the contraction, then

\begin{align}
\nabla (\nabla_u dh ) &= \nabla(c^1_1 ( u\otimes \nabla dh)) \\
&=c^1_1 \nabla (u\otimes \nabla dh) \\
&= c^1_1( \nabla u \otimes \nabla dh + u \otimes \nabla \nabla dh)
\end{align}

In particular, it means for all $X, Y$ and using [Ricci identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183615/deriving-ricci-identity-for-co-vector-fields),

\begin{align}
\nabla (\nabla_u dh ) (X, Y) &= (\nabla_{\nabla_X u} dh) (Y)+ \nabla_X \nabla_u dh (Y)\\
&= (\nabla_{\nabla_X u} dh) (Y)+ \nabla_u \nabla_X dh (Y) + R(u, X)dh (Y)
\end{align}

thus

$$\big( \nabla (\nabla_u dh ) - \nabla_u \nabla dh \big)(X, Y) = (\nabla_{\nabla_X u} dh) (Y)+ R(u, X)dh (Y).$$

so as expected the curvature terms come out. Also we have $\nabla u$. In general, when calculating
$$ \nabla^k \nabla_u dh- \nabla _u \nabla^k dh,$$
you have to differentiate $u$ $k$-times and use Ricci identity $k$-times. I guess there won't be a nice formula.

Comment: Thank you. Aren't you missing $-\nabla_{[u,X]}d(Y)$ when you use the curvature tensor to commute the two covariant derivatives?

Comment: @Duca_Conte Note that the notation $\nabla_X \nabla_u dh (Y) = \nabla\nabla dh (X, u, Y)$, but not $\nabla_X (\nabla_u (dh) )(Y)$ (the latter is like taking $\nabla u$ first then taking $\nabla_X$, which is not tensorial with respect to $u$)

Comment: that is a confusing notation, but I do not know if there is another better notations.